# Sprintf error to send email via c on centos 6.2

Tags: c, email, centos

We are trying to send several emails via C language on a centos 6.2 platform. Below are the codes. The error is  warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function `sprintf`.

How to solve this issue?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define cknull(x) if((x)==NULL) {perror(""); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
#define cknltz(x) if((x)<0) {perror(""); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
#define LIST_LEN 4


void main()                                          
{                                                                       
    char tmp[256]={0x0};                                                
    char fpBuffer[512]={0x0};                                           
    char email_list[LIST_LEN][256]={  {"****@gmail.com"},             
                               {"****@gmail.com"},             
                               {"***@gmail.com"},         
                               {0x0}};                                  
    int i=0;                                                            
    char *filename = "";                                                                    
    for(i=0;*email_list[i]>0x0;i++)                                
    {                                                                   
        cknull(strcpy(tmp, email_list[i]));                             
        cknltz(sprintf (fpBuffer,                                       
            "/usr/bin/mailx -s '%s %s' %s < %s",                        
            "Please Review:",                                           
            filename,                                                   
            tmp,                                                        
            filename));                                                 
        if(system (fpBuffer)==(-1))                                     
        {                                                               
            perror("email failure");                                    
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                         
        }                                                               
    }                                                                   
}
```

Comment: `int main(void)` in C99.

Comment: @MikeKwan: Even better, thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: I added and left char *filename = "";    the I get error as 
sh: TEST: No such file or directory
sh: TEST: No such file or directory
sh: TEST: No such file or directory. If I add a message to it give me another error  warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âsprintfâ

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking the prototype, as pointed out. There a couple of more issues I felt worth mentioning:

This:

```
*email_list[i]>0x0
```

assumes that `char` is unsigned, or at least that all valid characters are greater than 0. This is not a valid assumption for portable code, so it's better to write this as:

```
email_list[i][0] != '\0'
```

I would also write the sentinel (the end value in the initializer for `email_list`) as just plain `""`, why be more verbose with a (hex!) numerical constant when an empty string is what you mean?

The final thing I was going to mention was a suggestion to use `snprintf()`, but since that has portability problems of its own it's perhaps not a very reasonable suggestion after th above. :)

Comment: I done the changes ready email_list[i][0] != '\0' but I change this too {0x0}};? I have added the stdio.h library but yet I get errors as stated in the above reply.